# Digital asset links verification with SSL client certificates

Tags: android, https, client-certificates, trusted-web-activity, digital-assets-links

I have a web app, which is accessible over https, but requires ssl client cert to access any data on the app domain.

I want to convert it to a TWA, but I have a problem with the address bar, which is not hiding on first app launch. 
The thing is that during first launch assetlinks.json file is not accessible until the user selects a certificate to use. After choosing a certificate and killing the TWA app (but not killing chrome) and then launching the app again, everything works fine and the address bar is hidden.

Is there any way to delay the assetlinks verification until the user selects a cert? 
Another way, which I did think of was to restart the whole TWA app somehow from on-page javascript code (it should be possible to detect if a user just selected a certificate by using cookies with expiration set to 'Session'), but I didn't find any information about restarting TWA/PWA apps from on-page code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to delay the `assetlinks.json` generation.